# Вывод символов в консоль

Tags: c++

недавно я начал консольную игру "Дурак",и столкнулся с такой проблемой при выводе мастей карт что например вместо бубей или остального он выводит "?".

Прошу помочь, кто нибудь знает как можно вывести разные символы в консоль?

P.S
Почитал что то про Юникод но все равно ничего не понял,кроме того что это точно можно как то сделать.

P.S 
Или может быть есть для c++ типо как на Ардуино,  чтобы самому нарисовать какой то символ для вывода?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вывод разных символов в консоль](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/869868/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c)

Comment: Не понял. Зачем вам второй вопрос? Вы ведь это уже спрашивали, и вам показали, как.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat нет мне никто не показалал как все ответы не приводят ни к чему все равно выводится "?"

Comment: Так могли бы ответить на наши комментарии к тому вопросу и сказать об этом. У меня, например, тот способ работает.

Comment: Не стоит постоянно задавать один и тот же вопрос многократно. Минус за создание мусорных дубликатов вопроса.

Comment: Укажите какая используется консоль/операционная система. Приведите пример кода вывода символа, который некорректно отражается на экране.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно проблема заключается в локализации. Без кода трудно сказать. Рискну предположить, что у вас в коде имеется следующая строка локализации : `setlocale(LC_ALL,"Rus");`, её надо заменить на:

```
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
```

Необходимо поменять ширфт. Нажимаете правой кнопкой мыши на шапку консоли, выбираете свойства-> шрифт , и там найдёте выбираете шрифт `Lucida Console`.
И самое главно не забывайте добавить следующую библиотеку: `#include "windows.h"`

Comment: и как это поможет для вывода разных символов в консоль